# Null pointer exception when processing Linked List nodes

Tags: nullpointerexception, linked-list, duplicates

```
package LinkList2;
//import java.util.*;


public class Duplicates {

    public static void removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode head)
    {
        LinkedListNode current = head;

        while(current!= null && current.next!= null)
        {
            LinkedListNode curr = current;

            while(curr!=null)
            {
                if(curr.next.data==current.data) //Getting error at this line
                    curr.next = curr.next.next;

                else
                    curr = curr.next;
            }

            current = current.next;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedListNode first = new LinkedListNode(0,null,null);
        LinkedListNode head = first;
        LinkedListNode second = first;


        for(int i=1; i< 8; i++)
        {
            second = new LinkedListNode(i%2, null, null);
            first.setNext(second);
            second.setPrevious(first);
        }

        System.out.println(head.printForward());
        removeDuplicates(head);// Getting error at this line
    }

}
```

Getting null pointer exception in the above code. When I try to run the above code, it gives null pointer exception.
Please help me with my mistake.

Below is the implementation of LinkList where all the methods are defined

```
 class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    public LinkedListNode prev;
    public LinkedListNode last;
    public int data;
    public LinkedListNode(int d, LinkedListNode n, LinkedListNode p) {
        data = d;
        setNext(n);
        setPrevious(p);
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (this == last) {
            last = n;
        }
        if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
            n.setPrevious(this);
        }
    }

    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode p) {
        prev = p;
        if (p != null && p.next != this) {
            p.setNext(this);
        }
    }   

    public String printForward() {
        if (next != null) {
            return data + "->" + next.printForward();
        } else {
            return ((Integer) data).toString();
        }
    }

    public LinkedListNode clone() {
        LinkedListNode next2 = null;
        if (next != null) {
            next2 = next.clone();
        }
        LinkedListNode head2 = new LinkedListNode(data, next2, null);
        return head2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an exception just because of the following condition:

```
while(curr != null)
```

Replace it with `while(curr != null && curr.next != null)` this way you can check if you have the next element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that here:

```
while(curr != null)
{
   if(curr.next.data==current.data) //Getting error at this line
      curr.next = curr.next.next;
   else
      curr = curr.next;
}
```

You are accessing the `curr.next.data` where you are not checking if that node is `null` or not. This through your `NullPointerException`.

To fix your problem is to check on the while loop, if the `.next` is also not null.

```
while(curr != null && curr.next != null)
{
   if(curr.next.data==current.data) //Getting error at this line
      curr.next = curr.next.next;
   else
      curr = curr.next;
}
```

In other words, you are not checking if your next node is actually the end of the linked list (i.e null). If you need in your program logic to handle this **separately**, then you should remove the check from the while loop, and implement this check differently.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.